# Getting invalid csv from yahoo finance

Tags: csv, explode, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to get data from this url, but the column description seems to be in an invalid format which makes it impossible for me to explode everything correctly into an array

> http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2013&d=27&e=2&f=2013&g=m

This is a part of the result I´m getting. As you can see, with Adj Close 2014 is something wrong. When Im´exploding,

> Close2014

is bound together

> Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
>   2014-03-03,1206.75,1226.99,

Is something wrong with my url or is there a bug in the api??

Comment: It may not be visible, but I would imagine it's a newline character that separates them. Check for newlines.

Comment: Thank you David, it was indeed a newline character